# Function to find whether the number is contact list android

Tags: android, performance, android-contacts

Hi everyone i'am currently developing an android game, it uses your phone number when you first use the game(it is for an identification of the user).
It is an social game at some time when the user requests it returns a list of people who are currently online(playing the game),as json array(there phone number,name,photo)and from the data received you need to filter it out and display in two list views. The filtering done by this method:

1)Each element from JSON data(each person)if there phone number is found in     user's contact list then is displayed in the first listview

2)if the number is not found in users contact list it is displayed in second listview.

But my doubt is that if the JSON array returns details of 10 people, you need to check for this 10 people whether they are in user's contact list.And does this kind of a technique  takes a lot of time and creates delay in the UI..?

If yes please suggest me some other method.

Also please tell me how can I check whether a number is in user's contact list(I make the users upload there number to server without any country code).

So please in the number finding method you need to end the checking one a number has been fully completed.(starting from the end.

eg : 8086934565 (no saved in database) +918086934565(no in contact list)
then we need to start from last so that

5==5 then continue

6==6 then continue

till any of the no (+918086934565 or 8086934565) ends without breaking any equivalent condition.

eg for numbers +918086934565 and 8086933365 
checking from the last

5==5,6==6, 5!=3 there the equivalent condition goes wrong and hence it should get out from the loop with a flag ie the numbers are not equal.

Please write me the  function to do this or tell me an alternative method.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, that's painful to read...haha...You're suggesting using phone numbers to identify users in a multiplayer matchmaking scenario? That's taboo...If you return a JSON array of users phone numbers, names, and photos, your app will almost certainly be permanently banned from the market and possibly your entire account. That is about the biggest security risk that I can possibly think of, you might as well have a textfield where everybody types in their social security number and it posts it to craigslist. Basically any of your users could just repeatedly initiate games with people and get names photos and phone numbers of 10 random people at a time by capturing the plain text JSON data coming back. If I were you I'd look into the facebook sdk for authentication or Google Play Game Services for multiplayer matchmaking unless the core mechanics of your game rely on phone numbers specifically, in which case by it's very nature is just not going to fly with users. Asking someone to write you a function to do that is most likely never going to happen on stackoverflow. I'm not even going to get into the last part of the question...This has to be a troll attempt...lol